# Why is mail not sent? (Django)

Tags: python, django, email, view

I've written this code and I cannot figure out why the mail is not sent. In this code I check the POST field of the class request and I get the IP address inserted in a form. Once gotten the IP address I make a call to the server indicated by the IP and then I would like to send an email with the text of the response.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Server
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import ServerForm
import requests
from time import sleep
from django.core.mail import send_mail
def startPing(request):
    servers = Server.objects.all()
    context = {"servers": servers}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        indirizzoIP = request.POST.get('indirizzoIP')
        timer = request.POST.get('timer')
        indirizzoIP = "http://" + indirizzoIP
        while True:
            response = requests.get(indirizzoIP)
            if response != "":
                response = "Server OK"
                send_mail(
                    'Report server',
                    '{}'.format(response),
                    'from@',
                    ['to@'],
                    fail_silently=False,
                )   
                print(response)
        sleep(float(timer)*3600)
        
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', context)
```

EDIT

When I compile the form with the server IP, in the console I don't see any error. I tried to remove the sendmail function and in the console I see this:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 23, 2022 - 09:28:15
Django version 3.2.6, using settings 'serverControl.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[23/Sep/2022 09:28:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6354
Server OK
Server OK
```

Comment: Any errors showing up?!

Comment: you have defined a function but never called it.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, which function?

Comment: in your code you are defining the function `startPing`. Your code will do absolutely nothing if you just define a function. You need to call it at some point. Also it looks you might be missing some imports.

Comment: Edited the code putting the imports. I call the function `startPing`in the urls.py @SembeiNorimaki

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: using `while True` is wrong idea - it may run all time and it may block rest of code - so it can't send it. You should run loop in separated `thread`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Dude its web url (function). it will get called from User interface event. its not simple function that you're needed to call manually to execute.

Comment: @GianmarcoPolizia have you configured   EMAIL_BACKEND properly?

Comment: @HemalPatel I used this configuration 

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'